# show F is differentiable at a point P in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: derivatives

I am trying to use the following definition to show that F is differentiable,

$F(a+h,b+k)-F(a,b)=L(h,k)+\epsilon(h,k)$

where L is the linear part and I hope epsilon is small.  Firstly, I am not certain I wrote it down correctly, does it look correct?

Now for,

$F=(x^2+2xy,3x+y^2)$

I calculated $F(a+h,b+k)-F(a,b)$ to be,

$$=(a^2+2ab+2ah+2ak+2bh+h^2+2hk,3a+b^2+2bk+3h+k^2)$$

I am confused what is the linear part and the epsilon part, and how to show the derivative exists at the point P=(a,b).  I am studying for an undergraduate exam.  Thanks.

Comment: That should be $(2ah+2ak+2bh+h^2+2hk,2bk+3h+k^2).$ The linear part is everything with $h,k$ to the first power.

Comment: @zhw Ah!  I forgot to subtract the F(a,b) part..  Ok the new expression is then $(2ah+2ak+2bh+h^2+2hk,2bk+3h+k^2)$, I'm still confused how I show it exists at the point P=(a,b) using the definition.  The linear part is then $(2ah+2ak+2bh,2bk+3h)$ and epsilon is $(2hk+h^2,k^2)$?

Comment: @zhw I guess I'm just wondering if I'm done at this point.  Wouldn't it go to zero anyway without separating it into a linear and epsilon part?  Why do I need to separate the linear from the non-linear terms?

Comment: Bob, reread the definition of "differentiable".